# Trying to create a hover effect that turns menu button into an x shape with a shadow clone version of the button

Tags: html, css

Firstly just want to acknowledge that my title is confusing, so sorry about that. What I'm trying to achieve is the following effect on hover:

[image]

My site is here https://wordpress-493302-3130963.cloudwaysapps.com/

I have managed to do half of what I want to achieve using css transform, but cant see to create a shadow copy of the button like in the image above. My css is as follows

```
    .cta-button-menu:hover {
        transform:rotateZ(45deg) !important;
        background: #21B6CD !important;
        color: white !important;
        transition: 1s;
    }
```

If this can be achieved using JS or something else that could also work but CSS would be the preference.

*Didn't include html as its generated from a mega menu plugin but can do if required.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `::before` to apply this effect.

```css
.wrapper{
height:300px;
background-color:gray;
}

.btn, .btn::before{
  font-size:2rem;
  color:white;
  width:200px;
  height:70px;
  border:2px solid white;
  transition:all 0.3s linear;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.btn{
  position:relative;
  top:30%;
  left:30%;
  background-color:transparent;
}
  
.btn:hover {
   background-color:#21b6cd;
   transform: rotateZ(45deg);
   border:none;
}

.btn::before {
  content:"Book Now";
  background-color:transparent;
  position:absolute;
}

.btn:hover::before{
  transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
  background-color:#e72f54;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="btn">Book Now</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That solution is amazing thanks so much for the help with this. I'm having some sort of z-index or overlap issue though. Cant get the blue button to go over the red

Comment: You're welcome, I'm pleased to be of assistance. you can change the color of `button` and `before` together.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making 2 buttons/a tags:

```css
body {
  padding: 4em;
  background-color: black;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
}

.firstButton,
.secondButton {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.firstButton {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.button:hover .firstButton {
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  background: #E83054;
  visibility: visible;
}
.button:hover .secondButton {
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  background: #21B6CD;
}
```

```html
  <div class="button">
    <a class="firstButton" href="">Book Now</a>
    <a class="secondButton" href="">Book Now</a>
  </div>
```